# Check if an array position is really undefined or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to check if the value given in the callback of `JSON.stringify(obj, callback)` it's really undefined or not. The problem it's when is an array value not defined yet.

```
var a = new Array(3);
a[0] = true;
a[2] = undefined;

a.length;             // 3
a.hasOwnProperty(0); // true
a.hasOwnProperty(1); // false
a.hasOwnProperty(2); // true
a.hasOwnProperty(3); // false
(a[1] === a[2])      // true
```

Any ideas to detect if the position `[1]`, it's defined? Because the array have 3 elements for the JSON.stringify algorithm.

Comment: What about `a[1] === undefined` or `(a.length >= 2) && (a[1] === undefined)` ?

Comment: `(a[1] === a[2])`  it works correctly `undefined == undefined `

Comment: @collapsar I don't know the whole array because JSON.stringify do not pass it.

Comment: @EnZo You say you don't know the whole array - is this because `undefined` being passed as the value in `JSON.stringify`? If so, you have no way of knowing if it was explicitly set as undefined or not. This isn't then a simple "is this array index defined" question, so can you post a sample to reproduce the issue actually using `JSON.stringify`? Otherwise just loop the array and check `hasOwnProperty` as you have already done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to find out *assigned* (not necessarily *defined*) indexes in an array is an iterator function, like `forEach`, that ignores empty slots:

```js
var a = new Array(3);
a[0] = true;
a[2] = undefined;


defined = []
a.forEach(function(_, n) { defined.push(n) })
alert(defined)
```

Thus, you can use a dummy iterator to return only assigned items:

```js
a = []
a[1] = 11
a[2] = 22
a[3] = undefined
a[5] = 55
a[99] = 99
s = JSON.stringify(a, function(key, value) {
  if(Array.isArray(value))
    return value.filter(function() { return 1 });
  return value;
});

alert(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`replacer` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) in `JSON.stringify()` has the following:

- Parameter `key` - The name of the property being stringified
- Parameter `value` - The value of the property being stringified
- Bound `this` - The current object containing the property being stringified

You can "debug" each call and print the values like this:

```js
var a = new Array(3);
a[0] = true;
a[2] = undefined;

JSON.stringify(a, function(key, value) {
    var s = '\n-----------'
    s += '\nkey: ' + JSON.stringify(key);
    s += '\nvalue: ' + JSON.stringify(value);
    s += '\nthis: ' + JSON.stringify(this);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += s;
    return value;
});
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**This means you *do* have access to the original array in `this`.**

---

Therefore you can use a simple `hasOwnProperty` in combination as you suggested in your question to determine if it is defined or not:

```js
var a = new Array(3);
a[0] = true;
a[2] = undefined;

var result = JSON.stringify(a, function(key, value) {
    // value is undefined, either explicitly or really not set
    if(typeof value === "undefined") {
        // property not set at all
        if(!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return "really undefined";
        }
        else {
            // returning undefined from the callback will set the value to null,
            // so I give another value here to demonstrate the check
            return "explicitly undefined";
        }
    }
    
    // has an actual value so just return it
    return value;
}, " ");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

Something worth highlighting as I mentioned in the codes comments, you have to be careful with returning `undefined` from the callback. As the MDN article I linked to at the top states:

> **Note:** You cannot use the replacer function to remove values from an array. If you return undefined or a function then null is used instead.

This is why the debug snippet shows nulls for array entries 1 and 2.